# How to extract the column data/values with latest timestamp in db2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, db2

From below table I want to extract the column values (C_Number) with the latest TimeStamp buy comparing  with current system timestamp from db2 table? Please help.

Example: In Table "Computer" there are 3 columns i.e

```
C_Number    |              C_Data      |                TimeStamp
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12-DFHK     |              Yes         |              2013-08-14 07:33:05.29

13-DFCC     |              Yes         |              2013-08-18 07:45:05.29
```

Form the above table how can i extract the Column "C_Number" values with latest Timestamp(in this above table latest timestamp is "2013-08-18 07:45:05.29" ) by comparing with current system time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT C_Number FROM Computer
WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM Computer);
```

Answer (score 2):

one more efficient way to achive your purpose is the following:

```
SELECT C_Number
FROM Computer
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY ;
```